# Get seconds between two dates and display it with human_time_diff()

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I want to calculate seconds between two dates and display the purchased x seconds,minutes,hours ago text on my WooCommerce page.

I have this function:

```
$t_time = get_the_time( __( 'd/m/Y g:i:s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID );



/* $gmt_time = strtotime( $post->post_date_gmt ); */

$t_timestamp = strtotime ($t_time);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Budapest');

$ido = date('d/m/Y g:i:s');

$current_time = strtotime(date('d/m/Y g:i:s'));

//$current_time = strtotime(date('d/m/Y g:i:s'));

$time_diff = $current_time - $t_timestamp;



if ( $time_diff > 0 && $time_diff < 24*60*60 )

$h_time = sprintf( __( '%s ago', 'woocommerce' ), human_time_diff( $t_timestamp, $current_time ));

else

    $h_time = get_the_time( $date_format, $order->ID );

}
```

Which outputs:

HTIME: 2014. szeptember 12.
time_diff: -2809
ido: 12/09/2014 5:36:17
t_time: 12/09/2014 5:23:06
current_time: 1418099777
t_timestamp: 1418102586

HTIME: 2 óra ago
gmt_time: 
time_diff: 5891
ido: 12/09/2014 5:36:17
t_time: 12/09/2014 3:58:06
current_time: 1418099777
t_timestamp: 1418093886

My question is: How can be the current time smaller then the purchase date? In my opinion 12/09/2014 5:36:17 is bigger than 5:23:06.

Every help is appreciated :)

I have tried DateTime object, but if I add it, my jQuery is corrupted, and some parts of page doesn't load. There are an Uncaught TypeError errors.

Comment: I don't think it's causing the issue, but `$current_time = strtotime(date('d/m/Y g:i:s'));` could be rewritten `$current_time = time();` and you should get the same result

Comment: Thanks :) I tried that already. But in this case I got for time_diff numbers like: time_diff: -7565832 which is nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the help of this code snippet.

http://www.intechgrity.com/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-php-using-php-5-3-oop-or-5-2-procedural/